# g++: fatal error: no imput files linux

Tags: c++, shell, linux-mint

I'm trying to compile on linux mint shell the following cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the most basic program possible since I just wanted to test compiling on shell

I tiped:

```
g++ -o hello.cpp hello
```

and as a result:

```
g++: error: hello: no such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no imput files
compilation terminated
```

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Misplaced `-o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's: 
g++ -o hello hello.cpp

The -o indicates the desired name of the output file